Flatten directories up to a certain depth with SQL
I have an sqlite table of files where each row represents a file.
A row contains the parent directory_id of the file, filename, a directory_id if file is a symlink, and file size in percent.
A symlink file can be valid (point to an existing directory) or broken (point to a missing directory)
I want to flatten this structure up to a certain depth. That is to include all leaf files and broken symlinks as the hierarchy is traversed plus valid symlinks at that depth, but not valid symlinks leading up to that depth. And, ultimately, the goal is to recalculate the size_percent for the flattened files but this is not the challenging part.
To illustrate, I'll ommit the size_percent from this example and focus on the flattening part:
Assume the hierarchy is the following
D1/
    D1F1
    D1F2
D2/
    D2F1 
    D2F2 -> D0/     # broken symlink
    D2F3 -> D1/     # valid symlink
D3/
    D3F1
    D3F2 -> D0/     # broken symlink
    D3F3 -> D2/     # valid symlink

My query flattens the structure completely until the leaf files and includes the broken symlink along the way just fine.
D1/
    D1F1
    D1F2
D2/
    D2F1
    D2F2 -> D0/
    D1F1
    D1F2
D3/
    D3F1
    D3F2 -> D0/
    D2F1
    D2F2 -> D0/
    D1F1
    D1F2

However, It is not clear to me how to generalize it such that it can support arbitrary depths instead of going all the way deep.
For instance, flattening to depth k = 2 should give:
D1/
    D1F1
    D1F2
D2/
    D2F1
    D2F2 -> D0/
    D1F1
    D1F2
D3/
    D3F1
    D3F2 -> D0/
    D2F1
    D2F2 -> D0/
    D2F2 -> D1/

The data for the example above and my query follow:
CREATE TABLE files AS WITH tmp(directory_id, filename, symlink, size_percent) AS (
    VALUES
    ('D1', 'D1 F1', NULL, 0.5),
    ('D1', 'D1 F2', NULL, 0.5),

    ('D2', 'D2 F1', NULL, 0.5),
    ('D2', 'D2 F2', 'D0', 0.3),
    ('D2', 'D2 F3', 'D1', 0.2),

    ('D3', 'D3 F1', NULL, 0.1),
    ('D3', 'D3 F2', 'D0', 0.2),
    ('D3', 'D3 F3', 'D2', 0.7)
)
SELECT * FROM tmp;


WITH RECURSIVE flattened(directory_id, filename, symlink, depth, size_percent) AS (

    SELECT
        directory_id,
        filename,
        symlink,
        0,
        size_percent
    FROM files
    WHERE symlink is NULL -- regular file
        OR symlink NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT directory_id FROM files) -- broken symlink file
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        files.directory_id,
        flattened.filename,
        flattened.symlink,
        flattened.depth + 1,
        flattened.size_percent * files.size_percent
    FROM flattened
    JOIN files ON (files.symlink = flattened.directory_id)
)

SELECT * FROM flattened
ORDER BY directory_id, depth, filename
;



I believe you could just add a WHERE clause such as
WHERE flattened.depth + 1 < 2


where 2 could be passed as a bound parameter and thus be WHERE flattened.depth + 1 < ?

However, the result is not as your expected result instead it is:-


i.e. D2F2 -> D1/ is not present (nor is it without the WHERE clause), perhaps this is a typo as without the WHERE clause the result is:-



i.e. the result is the same but with the 2 rows that have a depth of 2 excluded.

Additional re comments

To clarify, valid symlinks are to be either followed but not included in the result (which is the case without the where clause), or be included in the final result if and only if they show up at the desired depth

BUT, as I understand it, valid symlinks are excluded, so there is nothing to select D2F2 D1 so you have to somehow add that.
Perhaps consider (probably not exactly what is required, but may be a move in a direction that would suit):-
WITH RECURSIVE flattened(directory_id, filename, symlink, depth,symlink_depth, size_percent) AS (

    SELECT
        directory_id,
        filename,
        symlink,
        0,
        0, /* ADDED symlink depth */
        size_percent
    FROM files
    WHERE symlink is NULL -- regular file
        OR symlink NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT directory_id FROM files) -- broken symlink file
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        files.directory_id,
        flattened.filename,
        flattened.symlink,
        flattened.depth + 1,
        /* ADDED determing symlink depth */
        flattened.symlink_depth + coalesce(flattened.symlink NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT directory_id FROM files),0),
        flattened.size_percent * files.size_percent
    FROM flattened
    JOIN files ON (files.symlink = flattened.directory_id)
    WHERE flattened.depth +1 < 2 /* depth limiter */
),
/* Add additional(s) where symlink depth is greater than 0 ???? */
a AS (
    SELECT 
        directory_id,
        /* probably not correct BUT where does D1 come from (query wise)? */
        filename, 'D'||symlink_depth, 
        depth,symlink_depth,size_percent 
    FROM flattened 
    WHERE symlink_depth > 0)

SELECT * FROM flattened UNION ALL SELECT * FROM a
ORDER BY directory_id, depth, filename
;

This results in:-


albeit that the symlink D1 (valid) has been cobbled together (perhaps what is missing is a directory having it's owning directory)


Thanks for taking a look at this! AddingWHERE flattened.depth + 1 < 2 was my initial intuition as well, however, as you point out, it does not address the issue here because D2F2 although being a symlink, is also a regular file too that exists at depth 1, but it doesn't end up in the final result. The children of the symlink are depth 2, but the symlink file itself is at level 1

To clarify, valid symlinks are to be either followed but not included in the result (which is the case without the where clause), or be included in the final result if and only if they show up at the desired depth
